# Loading gif bind to ajaxSend event, does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, bind, loading

I'm trying to get my ajax loading gif to work. The Ajax works fine. But it doesn't seem to trigger displaying the spinner to display.

Here is my DIV and my CSS. I know this displays properly because i've tested it without the "display:none".

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;"></div>

.spinner {
    background: url('images/spinner.gif') !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -16px; /* half width of the spinner gif */
    margin-top: -16px; /* half height of the spinner gif */
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1234;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 32px; /* width of the spinner gif */
    height: 34px; /*hight of the spinner gif +2px to fix IE8 issue */
}
```

Here's my javascript. Note the "bind" to the "ajaxSend". 
While the ajax call works properly on my page, it does not trigger the spinner from showing. It also does not trigger the alert().

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
        alert('triggered'); //This does not seem to trigger
        $(this).show();    // This does not seem to trigger
    }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

 $("#confirmbutton").on("click", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $.post( "/bm/form/save", $( ".form" ).serialize(), function() {

        })
            .done(function(data) {
                //do stuff
                alert( "done" );

            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "There was a problem saving!" );
            })
            .always(function() {
                alert( "finished (always)" );
        });


    });
```

Comment: Try to bind the listener to the document instead of #spinner.

Comment: You're right. I tried $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function() etc... and now it works. But why? And how can i give u points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
  alert("foo");
});
```